# Using qunit and sinon to test a jquery click

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, qunit

I have the following method in my code:

```
SignUpEvents = function () {

    return {
        Init: function () {

            $("#payBtn").click(function () {
                  EventTracker.Track("event", "name", "property"());
            });
        }
    }
}();

$(document).ready(SignUpEvents.Init);
```

I want to test that when the `payBtn` is clicked, the `EventTracker.Track()` method is called.

Here is my attempt:

```
QUnit.module("Sign Up Test");

QUnit.test("Sign up test", function (assert) {
    setUpSignUpEvents();
    var EventTrackerStub = sinon.stub(EventTracker, "Track");

    const $fixture = $("#qunit-fixture");
    $fixture.append(htmlPayButton());

    $("#payBtn").click();

    assert.ok(EventTrackerStub.calledOnce, "EventTracker.Track called");
    EventTracker.Track.restore();
});

function setUpSignUpEvents() {
    SignUpEvents.Init();
}

function htmlPayButton() {
    return '<a id="payBtn">60.00</a>';
}
```

However I am getting a failed test saying 'expected true but was false' - can anyone point out where I'm going wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Looks like you call `setUpSignUpEvents` *before* you add the button to the DOM, so the click handler would never get registered. You may just be able to reorder things:

```
QUnit.test("Sign up test", function (assert) {
    const $fixture = $("#qunit-fixture");
    $fixture.append(htmlPayButton());

    // NOTE THE SWAP HERE
    setUpSignUpEvents();
    var EventTrackerStub = sinon.stub(EventTracker, "Track");

    $("#payBtn").click();

    assert.ok(EventTrackerStub.calledOnce, "EventTracker.Track called");
    EventTracker.Track.restore();
});
```